# ORDER BY with DISTINCT gives ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I trying to use oracle order by with select statement but it causes an Exception:

> ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression.

```
 select distinct usermenu.menuname
 from   usermenu, userpermission
 where  userpermission.menuno = usermenu.menuno 
 and    userpermission.userno = 1
 order by userpermission.menuno;
```

Comment: *"not working properly"* isn't a problem statement at all. Tell us clearly what's not working. Also add sample data and your expected output and what output you get currently. Don't add them as comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55556262/edit) your question.

Comment: Did you try: `order by usermenu.menuno`? Also, I believe `order by` columns should also appear in the `select` list.

Comment: You order by `userpermission.menuno` but this is not a column of the select projection.

Comment: see deeply the statement then you fined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's `DISTINCT` or an aggregate function in the `SELECT` statement's column list, `ORDER BY` a column which isn't part of the `SELECT` column list won't work.

Here's an example, based on Scott's schema.

This works OK, although `D.LOC` isn't selected:

```
SQL> select d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  order by d.loc;

DNAME          ENAME
-------------- ----------
SALES          BLAKE
SALES          TURNER
SALES          ALLEN
SALES          MARTIN
SALES          WARD
SALES          JAMES
RESEARCH       SCOTT
RESEARCH       JONES
RESEARCH       SMITH
RESEARCH       ADAMS
RESEARCH       FORD
ACCOUNTING     KING
ACCOUNTING     MILLER
ACCOUNTING     CLARK

14 rows selected.
```

Now, add `DISTINCT` - basically, that's what you have:

```
SQL> select distinct d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  order by d.loc;
order by d.loc
         *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
```

The same goes for aggregate functions, such as `COUNT`:

```
SQL> select d.dname, e.ename, count(*)
  2  from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  group by d.dname, e.ename
  4  order by d.loc;
order by d.loc
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression


SQL>
```

So, what to do? Order by something else. Alternatively, use the current query as an inline view, join it with the table that contains the column you'd want to order the result by and it'll *work*:

```
SQL> select x.dname, x.ename
  2  from (select distinct d.dname, e.ename
  3        from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  4       ) x
  5       join dept d1 on d1.dname = x.dname
  6  order by d1.loc;

DNAME          ENAME
-------------- ----------
SALES          TURNER
SALES          JAMES
SALES          BLAKE
SALES          WARD
SALES          MARTIN
SALES          ALLEN
RESEARCH       SMITH
RESEARCH       FORD
RESEARCH       ADAMS
RESEARCH       SCOTT
RESEARCH       JONES
ACCOUNTING     MILLER
ACCOUNTING     KING
ACCOUNTING     CLARK

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks dear but how to solve this select statement I'm trying to solve but it's not work. please guide me in this example.

Comment: I can’t even begin to explain how much your help meant to me.